# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method ethGetBlockByNumber(DefaultBlockParameter, boolean) from the type Ethereum

Tags: java, ethereum, go-ethereum

I am not able to understand what is wrong with my code.

```
public void GetLatestBlock() throws Exception{
    List<EthBlock.TransactionResult> txs = Web3j.ethGetBlockByNumber(DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, 
    true).send().getBlock().getTransactions();
    //Ttxs =TestGet();
    
    txs.forEach(tx -> {
      EthBlock.TransactionObject transaction = (EthBlock.TransactionObject) tx.get();

      System.out.println(transaction.getFrom());
    });
```

It shows error :
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method ethGetBlockByNumber(DefaultBlockParameter, boolean) from the type Ethereum

I want to get lastblock's receipt for calculate the hashrate.

please give me some advice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need an instance of `Web3j` to call its instance methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Web3j.ethGetBlockByNumber** is not static (there is no **static** modification in signature of **ethGetBlockByNumber**). You must replace class name **Web3j** by instance (object of type Web3j) **Web3j**.

For example:

```
Web3j web3j = new Web3j(); // Or another way to create object of type Web3j
web3j.ethGetBlockByNumber(DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, 
    true).send().getBlock().getTransactions();
```